# Who has the most informations about the poneglyph?

Tags: one-piece

I was wondering who has the most informations about the poneglyph ? like their origin, how they was introducing into the One Piece world, their purpose and their meaning ?

So basically who gathered the most knowledge about it and still alive ?

[image]

Comment: It would be most logical to assume that its creators, the Kozuki Family, would have the most knowledge about it, and according to the wiki, Oden's death also ended the family's knowledge on reading and writing them. Unless 1) Someone close to the family was told of its secrets 2) Or someone found out about the knowledge via other means, I guess the information someone has on them is pretty much the same with those who know them, albeit the surviving family members' info on them might be a bit more than others. I'll defer to someone who can give a better answer.

Comment: Also probably the remaining members of Roger's crew, since Rayleigh mentions they figured out the Void Century secrets. Though considering how he also said none of them could read the Phoneglyphs like Robin, I'm not sure if they fit in this group.

Comment: In my opinion, the individuals most likely to know the most are the GOROSEI, the five elders, from what i understand,  have been alive for centuries and have not aged a bit, and they also know pretty much what happened in the void century, which explains why they destroyed Ohara, Nico robins home, to keep the information from spreading to the rest of the world.  They would rather keep this knowledge a secret for some unknown reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Roger's Crew.

When Robin discusses the Poneglyphs with [Silvers Rayleigh](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Silvers_Rayleigh),

> Robin spoke up and asked about the Void Century, explaining to Rayleigh her findings from the Poneglyph in Skypiea. Rayleigh replied that he did indeed find out the history of it, but advised that she continue looking for it on her own; he explained that if he told her at present, she would not be prepared for it nor have the strength and resources necessary to truly take advantage of the information.

Apparently, Roger couldn't read the poneglyphs, but could still understand them.

> In regards to Roger using the lost Poneglyph script on the Shandoran Belfry, he cryptically stated that Roger could simply hear the voice of all things.

So yeah, they know the true story and what happened in the Void Century. I would wager Robin is the most knowledgeable person after them.

Comment: Don't underestimate the world gouvernment. They are the ones that hid the now hidden knowlede in the first place. As stated in Law's backstory, they know about D. plus Sir Kroko and that Cipher Pol-guy presumably got their knowlede about the Porneglyphs from them. Roger learned some first hand knowlede about the stones themselfs but at least as close 2nd, I'd add the Celestial Dragons.